# App crashes as the device cannot find the camera

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, android-camerax

I am facing an issue with the camera of my device. The app requires taking a picture using the Back lens, but the CameraProvider cannot find any camera unless the device is restarted. The device that I am using has a front as well as a back camera. This issue occurs randomly and is not resolved unless the device is restarted.

Not sure what is causing the issue as I tried to update the camerax library version as well.

```
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-view:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.1.0'
```

Crash:

```
2022-10-10 14:11:04.079 15950-16056/com.test.app E/CameraValidator: 
Camera LensFacing verification failed, existing cameras: []
2022-10-10 14:11:04.082 15950-16056/com.test.app W/CameraX: Retry 
init. Start time 20600357 current time 20602006
androidx.camera.core.impl.CameraValidator$CameraIdListIncorrectException: Expected camera missing from device.
    at androidx.camera.core.impl.CameraValidator.validateCameras(CameraValidator.java:97)
    at androidx.camera.core.CameraX.lambda$initAndRetryRecursively$2$androidx-camera-core-CameraX(CameraX.java:342)
    at androidx.camera.core.CameraX$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:10)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No available camera can be found
    at androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector.select(CameraSelector.java:82)
    at androidx.camera.core.impl.CameraValidator.validateCameras(CameraValidator.java:83)
    at androidx.camera.core.CameraX.lambda$initAndRetryRecursively$2$androidx-camera-core-CameraX(CameraX.java:342) 
    at androidx.camera.core.CameraX$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:10) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
2022-10-10 14:11:04.603 15950-16056/com.test.app D/CameraValidator: 
Verifying camera lens facing on TC51, lensFacingInteger: null
2022-10-10 14:11:05.154 15950-16056/com.test.app E/CameraValidator: 
Camera LensFacing verification failed, existing cameras: []
2022-10-10 14:11:05.154 15950-16056/com.test.app E/CameraX: The 
device might underreport the amount of the cameras. Finish the initialize task since we are 
already reaching the maximum number of retries.
2022-10-10 14:11:05.187 15950-15950/com.test.app E/CameraFragment: 
Camera initialization failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided camera selector 
unable to resolve a camera for the given use case
```

Code:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {

    cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireContext())

    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.camera_fragment, container, false)
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    // Request camera permissions
    if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
        binding.viewFinder.post { startCamera() }
    } else {
        activityResultLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    }

    binding.close.setOnClickListener {
        setNavigationResult(null)
        findNavController().navigateUp()
    }
}

private fun startCamera() {
    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
        val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
        bindPreview(cameraProvider)
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()))
}

 private fun bindPreview(cameraProvider : ProcessCameraProvider) {

    view?.let {

        val preview: Preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()

        val cameraSelector: CameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
            .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
            .build()

        val imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
                .setTargetRotation(it.display.rotation)
                .build()

        preview.setSurfaceProvider(binding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)

        try {
            cameraProvider.unbindAll()
            cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this as LifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, imageCapture, preview)
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Timber.e("Camera initialization failed: ${e}")
        }
    }
}


override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    cameraExecutor.shutdown()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your device may have a hardware problem with the camera.  You can look at the output of `adb shell dumpsys media.camera` if you have Android developer tools set up, to see what kinds of camera devices the device makes available.

If it doesn't list a back camera there, then there's a low-level problem with it, and CameraX isn't going to be able to fix that.

A camera with some nearly-failing hardware sometimes works right at boot, but fails soon after (or after first use).  Eventually it'll just always fail.

Comment: Thanks @Eddy Talvala, I suspected it could be a device problem as it happens on the device that I am using. It's a Zebra PDA and it doesn't happen on some of the other devices at all.